# onItemClickListener and view not clickable

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false">



<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/MXname"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:gravity="left"
android:text="Slashdot"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/MXtnumber"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:gravity="left"
android:text="10 minutes ago" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="false" 
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="right"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/MXdialer"
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:gravity="right"
android:src="@drawable/lcall_button" />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have a listview with the ROW xml listed above and below is the code from activity:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position , long id)
 {
Log.d("ItemClick","in the list"+ String.valueOf(view.getId()));
if (view==findViewById(R.id.MXdialer))
        {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Name and/or Phone number empty"+String.valueOf(id),                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

the Logcat does indicate the onitemClick being execuated but toast never works and view.getid() always returns -1. I have read the articles on onitemclicklisterner and have already made all the views as not focusable and not clickable but the still no go. Please suggest

Comment: can you show us the getview method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`view` is the root layout of the clicked list item not the any child in the item layout. So the Toast will never show.

If you want click on any specific child view, set the `onClickListener` to that child, but then the `OnItemClickListener` will not be called. Either of the two will get called. The child views clikclistener takes priority.

Comment: as indicated above I have tried setting the onclick XML attribute to a method but that method never gets called. Does anybody know how to find what item in a listview is being clicked?. I have tried all possible things thanks

Comment: do you know how to set the onclicklistener on child view?

Comment: Just as a note, If somebody wants onclicklisterner its needs to be done through custom adapter and then override getview() method and in there setup the Onclicklistener on selected views. thanks

Answer (score 0):

for your if statement try this as not sure you can compare objects like the way your doing it.

```
int viewID=view.getId();

    if(viewID== R.id.MXdialer)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name and/or Phone number empty"+String.valueOf(id),                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: ok then what is the way to find what is being clicked? I have also tried to set the onclick xml attribute to a method and that does not work as well

Comment: you have the view so you know whats being clicked.  THE view from onclick(View view)

Comment: yes but that does not gets called. any more ideas, does somebody has a working code as an example somewhere?